# how to load a .BIN file in Java project?

Tags: java, file, import, load

bin file(en-token.bin) into my java project. I put the .bin file into the resource folder. But when I run this loading it shows NullpointerException.

```
 InputStream modelIn;
        try {
            modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            return null;
         }
```

I also tried to put the whole path of the .bin file but still didn't work. Then I tried to put the .bin file in the same package with the class this piece of code belongs to. It didn't work either. Is this the right way to load the .bin file? I can't use the local path cause I have to put it into the project so that it can run on other machine without downloading the same .bin file.

Comment: `modelIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/en-token.bin");`

Comment: Aha it works! Thanks so much for that. Just realize that I missed a "/" in the string... Thank you very much!

Comment: Appreciated, thanks too.

Comment: Hi really sorry but I just found that it was actually still loading the file in my local disk instead of the file in my resource package of my project..If I want to load it from the resource of the project how should I configure the path? Or any other operations?

Comment: If you start the application in the IDE, it is quite possible, that the loose classes and resource files are on the class path; and used. You can look into the jar with 7zip/WinZip, and move the jar elsewhere before starting it.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. Sorry I'm very new to Java and not sure which jar should I look into, and is it right that I put the .bin file directly in the resource folder in the project?

Comment: Yes, simply let it be zipped into the jar.

Comment: Ye but I can't find the jar of the whole project. It's a maven project, is there any difference?

Comment: So the file has the path `src/main/resources/en-token.bin`. On mvn install the jar should reside in your local maven repository .m2/...